# Capybara, Rails, Selenium, Chromedriver + ERR:CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I'm setting up Capybara with Selenium Webdriver in my Rails application, and I keep running into the following error:

```
Helpdesk Ticketing System assigning a ticket should mark ticket as assigned
     Failure/Error: visit tickets_path
     
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
         (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

My settings are as follows:

```
Capybara.server = :puma
Capybara.app_host = 'http://intranet.lvh.me'
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
```

In the logs it shows this before the failure, choosing a different port each time it runs:

```
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 4.3.6 , codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:56277
```

Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. I was missing:

`Capybara.always_include_port = true`

Comment: Thanks, that was an odd one... I have another test in my suite which does almost the same thing as a new test I was writing, but failing with the above error.

Once I added your line above all was well, so thank you!

Comment: @Joe I found the reason is I was using *_url instead of *_path route helper, was this your case too?

Comment: @hungmi that sounds familiar although I don't recall exactly now.

Answer (score 2):

I had set route-level URL defaults inside of `config/environments/test.rb` and that option pulls through to all parts of the application.

When I removed the line shown below, all my tests passed again.

```rb
# config/environments/test.rb
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = { 
  host: "server.localhost", 
  port: 3000 
}
```

Comment: That fixed it for me.

Comment: Removing the port setting worked for me, but the host setting was still needed.